# Perl pack function is broken?

Tags: perl, perl-module, pack

I have a header creation Perl script and it works great most of the time, but every once in a while the thing breaks. I'll get right down to the meat of it, given the CRC number 772423333 the PERL pack function breaks.

```
my $dec = 772423333;
my $broken = pack("N", $dec);
print "Good:\t", uc(sprintf("%x", $dec)), "\nBad:\t$broken"; # eg. 2E0D0A3EA5
```

Forgive me for not knowing how to print the readable HEX, but this is what it returns.

```
Good:   2E0A3EA5
Bad:    2E0D0A3EA5
```

How do I remove the `0D`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example output isn't what your program prints. Your program prints "bad" out that in binary (as if it were printable characters, though its not), not in hex.

It works here (once I pipe it to a hex dumper, so I can read it), but I'm on Linux.

Most likely, where you're going wrong is that you need to call `binmode` on your output file handle (or alternatively open it with a `:raw` layer); you are seeing newline to CRLF translation. If you add `binmode *STDOUT;` immediately before your print (in your example code), I suspect you'll get the expected output.

[ On Unix, there is no newline-to-CRLF translation, so it works ]

Comment: How do I open binmode on the string? Or should I output directly to file?

Comment: Your string ($broken) is fine. Your print is where the extra character is coming from. You need to binmode whichever filehandle you're writing it to. In your example, that's STDOUT, but in your actual code its probably something else—possibly even a socket.

Comment: The funny thing is our code had `binmode` on the file handle, but it was replaced with `:raw`. Eventually the `:raw` was removed due to versioning issues. And now we're full circle with `binmode` on the file handle.

Answer (score 3):

Stop using Windows? `0D0A` are the character codes of a Windows line ending (more commonly seen as `"\r\n"`), and you observe them because you are printing character `0A` (`"\n"`) to a handle (`STDOUT`) with the `:crlf` encoding, which automatically converts any `\n` characters to the sequence `\r\n`.

Call `binmode` on `STDOUT` to disable this encoding. Here's the view using an MSWin32 build of perl with the Cygwin utility `od`:

```
$ winperl -e 'print pack("N",772423333)' | od -c
0000000   .  \r  \n   > 245
0000005

$ winperl -e 'binmode STDOUT; print pack("N",772423333)' | od -c
0000000   .  \n   > 245
0000004
```